# Unable to start resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, resque

I am trying to use resque with active job. I am following the introductions specified in the [link](http://bica.co/2015/01/20/active-job-resque/)

When ever I tried to start resque with the following command

```
bundle exec rake resque:work
```

I get the following error

```
The controller-level `respond_to' feature has been extracted to the `responders` gem. Add it to your Gemfile to continue using this feature:
  gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'
Consult the Rails upgrade guide for details.
```

Please look at my Gemfile once

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

gem 'rails-api', "~> 0.4.0"

gem 'spring', :group => :development

gem "activerecord-import", "~> 0.4.0"

gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.0"

gem 'delayed_job'

gem "delayed_job_web"

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

gem "daemons"

gem 'resque'

gem 'responders'


# ADD-ONS

# Require smarter_csv for data import
gem "smarter_csv", "~> 1.0.19"
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.0"
gem "kaminari", "~> 0.16.0"
gem "api-pagination", "~> 4.0.0"
gem "colorize", "~> 0.7.5"
gem "versionist", "~> 1.4.0"
gem "httpclient", "~> 2.6.0.1"
gem "rest-client", "~> 1.7.0"
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
gem 'omniauth-facebook',"~> 2.0.1"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2","~> 0.2.6"
# git@github.com:baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable.git
gem 'devise-token_authenticatable'
gem "devise-encryptable" ,'~> 0.1.2'
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.5'
gem "bunny", ">= 1.7.0"
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem 'rantly', '~> 0.3.1'
gem 'forgery', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.8.3'
```

What is the problem ? I am not able to find the solutions online. 
I am using rails 4.2.5
Also active_model_serializers had to be pinned to 0.8.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes I did bundle install several times, I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My way (don't forget to start redis-server):

```
$ git clone  https://github.com/cristianbica/activejob-resque.git
$ cd activejob-resque/
$ bundle install
...
$ TERM_CHILD=1 LOGGING=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
activejob-resque]$ TERM_CHILD=1 LOGGING=1 QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
*** Starting worker test.lo:17635:*
*** Registered signals
*** Running before_first_fork hooks
*** Checking default
*** Sleeping for 5.0 seconds
*** resque-1.25.2: Waiting for *
...
```

Deprecation warnings excluded. Pay attention

```
$ bundle exec rake resque:work
set QUEUE env var, e.g. $ QUEUE=critical,high rake resque:work
```

You shoul set QUEUE enviromental variable at least.
Above action just for test, but try it first of all. Works for me.

Comment: I am trying this and getting back to you, in some time. Thanks

Comment: Its working for me. I need to figure out why it is not working with my back end application.

Comment: $ gem list | grep responders  responders(2.1.1) ?

Comment: responders gem is installed. version 2.1.1